# C preprocessor macro to generate functions possible?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, c99

is it possible to write a macro which generates from this call

```
WATCH(l1=g1+g2*g3)
```

this code?

```
TRACE(g1);
TRACE(g2);
TRACE(g3);
l1=g1+g2*g3;
TRACE(l1);
```

im not sure if this is possible at all, if yes please point me in the right direction.

Software used: arm-linux-gnu-gcc, Version 4.9.1, Target is a Cortex-M3 Board, Language is C99

regards,
memic

Comment: Consider using some other preprocessor (e.g. [GPP](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP) or `m4`) and/or generate your C++ code by your specialized program.

Comment: Avoid using preprocessor for complex stuff. It is difficult to debug and also you do not have the luxury of type checking

Comment: I suspect this is an XY problem. In C++, we'd probably solve the X problem by declaring all 4 vars as a custom type so its operators can be overloaded to print the arguments.

Comment: WATCH is a macro which i want to define to generate the code, which has other macros in it (TRACE)

Comment: Please edit your question to explain why do you ask, what compiler and operating system are you using, if you are coding in C or in C++, and what is your software doing.

Comment: Please explain what is your software doing.

Comment: Why the C++ tag if you're using C99 ?

Comment: @user2501 Possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

No. The macro would start by `#define WATCH(X) ...` and you can't parse `X` in the preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy (and probably impossible the way you are asking). Perhaps you want some [aspect-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)

Consider using some other preprocessor (e.g. [GPP](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP) or `m4`) and/or generate your C++ code by some specialized program or script that you would write.

You might also customize your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (at least on Linux, with a recent `gcc` or `g++`) using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/). This requires understanding GCC internals (notably Gimple representation) and writing in MELT an additional optimization pass which would do the transformation (so probably several weeks of work).

Comment: havent heard about aspect-oriented programming in c

Comment: @memic the original tag was c++.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with preprocessor alone, but it's possible with some TMP tricks like expression template, for example, you can take a look at the [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) library:

```
TEST_CASE( "Factorials are computed", "[factorial]" ) {
    REQUIRE( Factorial(0) == 1 );
    REQUIRE( Factorial(1) == 1 );
    REQUIRE( Factorial(2) == 2 );
    REQUIRE( Factorial(3) == 6 );
    REQUIRE( Factorial(10) == 3628800 );
}
```

This can produce message like below:

```
Example.cpp:9: FAILED:
  REQUIRE( Factorial(0) == 1 )
with expansion:
  0 == 1
```

Note that the last line `0 == 1`, how can it tells that the lhs is `0`, rhs is `1`, and the operator is `==`?, well, it's done through expression template, and the combination with macro just makes it easy to use.

Comment: The OP is using C (C99) - not sure why the question is tagged as C++ though.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible (afaics) with the operators in the macro call. But you can define a macro with a function like signature:

```
#define WATCH(l1,g1,g2,g3) \
TRACE(g1); \
TRACE(g2); \
TRACE(g3); \
l1=g1+g2*g3; \
TRACE(l1)
```

Would that help? And as always with compound statements I'd recommend to wrap them in a do ... while loop, like

```
#define WATCH(l1,g1,g2,g3) \
do { \
    TRACE(g1); \
    TRACE(g2); \
    TRACE(g3); \
    l1=g1+g2*g3; \
    TRACE(l1); \
} while(0)
```

So that it behaves like a single command; imagine

```
if( condition )  WATCH(l1,g1,g2,g3);
```

With an unprotected compound statement.

Comment: yea this is similar what user2501 suggested.. thx :) problem here is that the operators (+,*) a inside of the macro..

Comment: You mean the calls of the form `WATCH(l1=g1+g2*g3)` are already in the code and you cannot manually change them? Then you need some better text processing than cpp (patch, sed) as part of your build.

Comment: yes l1+g2+g*g3 is the code i want to execute and also trace the vars on the right before and the an the left after the line is executed

Comment: Oh. You mean you want to do that for arbitrary expressions?

Comment: yes, exactly, but as i see it, there is no easy solution

Comment: @memic No, there is no easy solution. You need a lot more than text preprocessing; you want to work on the language level. Of course you can always pass and parse strings, building your own little buggy incomplete run time expression interpreter. (Any plans for 2015?) In C# you could start to build true expression trees, in C++ you could perhaps explore how far you get with lambdas and variadic templates. But in C? You'd be better off with self modifying machine code.